# Getting "TypeError: file argument must be a non-empty string" when Cordova Build task

Tags: cordova, azure-devops, visual-studio-cordova

I am running a Cordova Build task in VSTS that builds for iOS the signing files attached:

[image]

However, when I execute the task, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: "file" argument must be a non-empty string
    at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:383:11)
    at spawnSync (child_process.js:519:38)
    at /Users/dummyuser/Desktop/dev/agent/_work/_tasks/CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7/1.3.11/lib/xcode-task-utils.js:55:31
    at _fulfilled (/Users/dummyuser/Desktop/dev/agent/_work/_tasks/CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7/1.3.11/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/dummyuser/Desktop/dev/agent/_work/_tasks/CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7/1.3.11/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/dummyuser/Desktop/dev/agent/_work/_tasks/CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7/1.3.11/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /Users/dummyuser/Desktop/dev/agent/_work/_tasks/CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7/1.3.11/node_modules/q/q.js:877:14
    at runSingle (/Users/dummyuser/Desktop/dev/agent/_work/_tasks/CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7/1.3.11/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/Users/dummyuser/Desktop/dev/agent/_work/_tasks/CordovaBuild_70e94267-15dc-434d-8973-023d766825d7/1.3.11/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
```

Tracing back through the code of [child_process](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/edb03cb65d51e336713d6af1134a7394c0776635/lib/child_process.js#L381), I am pretty confident this error is occurring because the file argument is not a string. Below is a snippet of the call chain:

**xcode-util-task.js**

```
var spawnResult = spawn(createKeychain, createKeychainArgs, { stdio: "inherit" });
```

**child_process.js**

```
function spawnSync() {
  var opts = normalizeSpawnArguments.apply(null, arguments);

...

function normalizeSpawnArguments(file, args, options) {
  if (typeof file !== 'string' || file.length === 0)
    throw new TypeError('"file" argument must be a non-empty string');
```

Indeed that does appear to be the case. The first argument of spawn(), createKeychain, is an object and not a string. I get the following when I print the object out:

```
{ [String: '/bin/bash']
  stdout: '/bin/bash',
  stderr: null,
  code: 0,
  cat: [Function: bound ],
  exec: [Function: bound ],
  grep: [Function: bound ],
  head: [Function: bound ],
  sed: [Function: bound ],
  sort: [Function: bound ],
  tail: [Function: bound ],
  to: [Function: bound ],
  toEnd: [Function: bound ],
  uniq: [Function: bound ] }
```

I'm sure I am missing something, but this one feels like it's a bug within the Cordova Build extension.

FYI
Node: 8.9.1, NPM: 5.5.1, Cordova Build: 1.3.11

Comment: Can you share the log on the OneDrive? (set system.debug to true, then queue build and share this log)

Comment: Do you use private build agent? Can you build the project manually through Command line on that build agent machine?

Answer (score 2):

had exactly the same problem... it was caused by the NodeJS Version (8.x) on the agent. Downgraded to 6.x and after that, the step was working ;)

It is also possible, to add a "Use Node 6.x" Task in your build..

Comment: I can't seem to see a task to force the version of node to use? is this a market place extension?

Comment: I found it. The task is called Node Tool Installer.